# noobie Iterating over list to display series

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, iteration

I'm trying to generate the fibonacci series here. Not necessarily looking for an answer specific to that series but why the loop I've created here won't generate a list with upto 20 values for an input of '0'.

So far I've tried appending within and before the loop. The result I get is [0,1]. It doesn't seem to add to the list beyond that.

```
series = []
value = input("Enter an integer: \n")
i = int(value)
series.append(i)
if series[0] == 0:
    series.append(1)
    for i in series[2:20]:
        series[i]=series[i-1]+series[i-2]
        series.append(i)
print(series)
```

Comment: Python does not pre-allocate space for lists. Hence `for i in series[2:20]` won't work as expected over a list of length 1.

Comment: `for i in LIST` iterates over values contained in the LIST, your `series[2:20]` will be empty, since the `series` has only 2 values, and you slice after second. Slicing outside of the list range gives empty list. So your `for` look is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

After doing `series.append(1)` you series values `[0,1]` only so `series[2:20] == []` and you iterate on nothing and fill in nothing. And you cannot access an index that is not already allocated, so you can't do `series[i]` and you did not reach that index yet, you just need to append the values

```
if series[0] == 0:
    series.append(1)
    for i in range(2, 20):
        series.append(series[i - 1] + series[i - 2])
```

- `series[2:20]` returns values of `series` from index 2 included to 20 excluded
- `range(2,20)` **generates** values 2 included to 20 ecluded

Comment: Great! This helps. Why was range(a,b) used instead of list[a:b]?

Comment: @Tom I've add this in the post. One retrieve values, the other generates numbers